# how to get jwt token in service worker

Tags: service-worker, workbox

I am trying to implement push notification (Push API). I only want logged in users to be able to receive notifications.

One of the events I need to implement is `pushsubscriptionchange` in my service worker so that i know that it's been changed and i should make a `fetch` request to my database. The current parameters I have is `old` and `new` subscription, but the problem that i am seeing is I don't have `jwt` token while sending that request. Which means that the api endpoint for this case stays unsafe and anyone can just execute it with `old` and `new` subscription.

If anyone grabs my subscription, he can somehow replace it with his own one and after that, execute the api call of my unsafe endpoint and from now on, he will receive the notifications instead of me.

I am looking for the best practice :

- put `jwt` in indexeddb in my app code and then in service worker, grab it from `indexeeddb`. This starts to be a problem because when user logs out, i have to take it out from indexeddb, when `jwt` token gets refreshed, i have to refresh it in indexeddb too. who knows what kind of bugs it's gonna introduce.
- another solution that i can think of is when user logs in, i have the code which unsubscribes him and then subscribes it. This way it seems fairly simple because someone else will never grab my subscription that easily. I am not sure though if this is the right way to go.

what do you think?

Comment: The endpoints are secret (by definition in the standard) and there isn't any security issue until you keep them secret. How can you replace the old endpoint with a new one if you don't know the old one?

Comment: I am talking about my api endpoints, not the push service endpoints. If I don't pass `jwt` token and have the api endpoint which just replaces old push endpoint with a new one, anyone would be able to call this api endpoint which is a security breach...

Comment: No, it's not a security issue... they can call your api but they don't know the old endpoint! So the api call will result in an empty operation.

Comment: can you store token in aync-storgae and then get jwt?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use JWT for authentication I believe your "regular JavaScript" (not Service Worker) already has access to an access token and is including it in all requests from the client to the server. Usually this access token lives in JS memory (some variable or so) and is then attached to the requests.

To get the JWT into the SW for API communication, you should use the postMessage API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). With that you can communicate between the code running inside the SW and on the page.

You could either send a msg to the page from the SW to ask for the token and then have the page side JS send it to the SW which could, in turn, use it for authentication. Or you could send whatever info the SW gets from the subscription change event to the page and have the page make the API calls.

Comment: the `pushsubscriptionchange` event happens whenever browser decides too. in that event, sending `postMessage` from sw to client is no way a good idea. indexeddb is still better . don't you think?

Comment: @NikaKurashvili why using `postMessage` isn't a good idea? That won't be done inside `pushsubscriptionchange` but when the JWT is first fetched or updated and then the parent sends a message to the SW with that token.

Comment: It's possible SW thread might stop/continue again with no reason. so if it stops and boots up/continues again, my jwt is lost . It should be stored somewhere in the db .